# Выбор вопроса, определяющего вид имён прилагательных

Tags: прилагательные

Есть два варианта определения:

> Она не ожидает, что погода будет **солнечной** завтра.
>
> Она не ожидает, что погода будет **солнечная** завтра

Какой вариант предпочтительнее для письменной речи? Как лучше спросить:

> **Какая** завтра будет погода?

или

> **Какой** завтра будет погода?

Есть общее правило для выбора правильного варианта?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

При выборе между падежами, а именно И.п. и Т.п., учитываются **две тенденции**:

**Т.п.**: книжный стиль, временной признак (отнесенный к определенному моменту):

чем? - солнечн**ой** погод**ой**

**И.п.**: разговорный стиль, постоянный признак:

что? - солнечн**ая** погод**а**

Эти факторы не являются абсолютными, они только учитываются при выборе падежа. Дополнительно: **в будущем времени чаще используется Т.п.**

На слух можно составить такие предложения (разговорный стиль):

Я не думаю, что погода завтра **будет солнечной**. Я не думаю, что завтра будет **солнечная погода**.

Прогноз на завтра: **Какая** завтра будет погода? Погода будет **солнечная**.

Таким образом, **собственное предположение** в разговорном стиле можно выразить в форме И.п.или Т.п. А вот прогноз погоды уже составлен, воспринимается как **нечто постоянное**, поэтому лучше использовать И.п.

Comment: Я вот долго не мог понять, что под `Т.п.` и `И.п.` имеются в виду падежи. Недружелюбно.

Comment: Ну да, это именительный и творительный падеж.

Comment: Разве долго? Вы задали мне этот вопрос через минуту после ответа, а уже через 40 секунд получили пояснения. К тому же это общепринятые обозначения. В любом случае извините, если что-то Вам показалось некомфортным.

Comment: Ну не в прямом смысле "долго" :) Просто, не сразу воткнулся о чём речь. И вообще я беззлобно, тем более, что я новенький тут. Сами знаете, когда спотыкаешься обо что-то, это не очень приятно. В любом случае спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Пожалуйста, спрашивайте, это очень хороший форум. Отвечают тут быстро, спорные вопросы обсуждаются коллективно, так что можете услышать несколько мнений.